# C# 2010 Express + SQL Server 2008 Express - Connection "Login failed"

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, connection

I am actually developing a Windows Forms Application with Visual C# Express 2010    which would use (read/write) data from a SQL Server 2008 Express DB

I have created my DB with SQL Server Management Studio (2008 Express), 
I understand the instance is named `ATLELAG786576\SQLEXPRESS`
My DB is called 'TEST'

Looking at my DB 'TEST' Properties in SQL Server Management Studio (2008 Express):
Under Files, I am (`ATLE\bneveux`) the owner of the DB

Looking under Security, Logins, Mylogin (ATLE\bneveux)

- My default DB is 'TEST'
- Server roles are 'public' + 'sysadmin'
- User Mapping DB 'TEST' User 'dbo' Default Schema 'dbo'

In my C# application

**app.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="connectionStringTestDb"
            connectionString="Data Source=ATLELAG786576\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\TEST.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings> </configuration>
```

**dbConnection.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SQLServerConnectionDemo
{
    class dbConnection
    {
        public static SqlConnection newCon;
        public static string connectionStringTestDb = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringTestDb"].ConnectionString;

        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            newCon = new SqlConnection(connectionStringTestDb);
            return newCon;
        }
    }
}
```

**dbAccess.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLServerConnectionDemo
{
    class dbAccess
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        public dbAccess()
        {
            conn = dbConnection.GetConnection();
        }

        //Method insert new in tblEmployees
        public void addEmployee(string Id, string Name, string Email)
        {
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            newCmd.Connection = conn;
            newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            newCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblEmployees VALUES ('"+ Id +"','"+ Name +"','"+ Email +"')";
            newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}
```

**in a form formEmployeeAdd.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SQLServerConnectionDemo
{
    public partial class formEmployeeAdd : Form
    {

        dbAccess access = new dbAccess();

        public formEmployeeAdd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            access.addEmployee(txtId.Text, txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Data successfully added");
        }
    }
}
```

And here the error message I always get when trying to run this process:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\TEST.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'ATLE\bneveux'.

Note that I have never really been able to add my Data Source in Visual C# 2010 Express so I could manage the DB from VS, I always get the following error message:

> Unable to open the physical file "D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\TEST.mdf". Operating system error 32: "32(Le processus ne peut pas accéder au fichier car ce fichier est utilisé par un autre processus.)".
>   An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\TEST.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
Initial Catalog=D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\TEST.mdf
```

with simply

```
Initial Catalog=TEST
```

Comment: Hi jeroenh, Just tried your proposition, it worked and solved my problem! Thank you for your quick reply!

(How do I mark this answer successful?)

Comment: Glad it works. There should be an 'accept' marker left of the question to the question. You can also upvote using the up arrow.

Comment: jeroenh, 

Can I abuse and ask you how to solve the possibility to use Visual C# 2010 Express to browse/manage the Database;

When I go 
Data Sources > New > Database > Dataset > New connection
I select "Data source" Microsoft SQL Server File... (sorry if the translation is not right I use a french version)
Then browse to my TEST.mdf file
When I click "Test connection" I now get the following error message "Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user 'ATLE\bneveux'."

Thank you!
Brice

Comment: Not entirely sure about VS Express, but you shouldn't need to browse to the .mdf file. You need to enter the SQL server name (COMPUTER\INSTANCE), and connect to the database name ('TEST' in your case).

Comment: VS Express definitely asked me to point to the .mdf file. 
I did + as you recommended changed the 'Initial Catalog' property to my Db name, and it worked ;)
Thanks mate for your help
Have a good day